# Menu background not changing completely

Tags: css

I am developing a menu bar. I amm done but left with the hover action. I am looking for the whole background of the menu to change but the menu background only changes behind the text.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NmFHW/) is the fiddle.

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="#">Zardari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kutta</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Here is the css,

```
.nav{background:#454545;line-height:1;overflow:hidden;position:relative; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;   padding-left:10px;}

.nav a{
    color:#fff;text-decoration:none;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-right:10px;
}

    .nav i{position:relative;top:-3px}
    .nav li{float:left;overflow:hidden}
    .nav ul{list-style:none;margin:0;overflow:hidden;padding:0;width:100%}
    .nav .active{background:#454545}
    .nav ul a:hover{
            color:#FFF;
            background:#000;            

    }
​
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I missed anything. Its a menubar.

Comment: Uhm, from what I understand you want the whole menu to change its background color to the one that appears when hovering the menu links..?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno: Not the whole menu but just the menu item.

Comment: Uhm, but the fiddle does that. No?

Comment: Is this the behavior you want: when you hover one li, you want the background of the whole menu to change.

Comment: If this is the case, it's not possible using css only, as there is currently no way to select (with a css selector) a parent element (in your case, the .nav element) from a child element (the li or a).

Comment: @Vucko: Sorry I am not using that.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno: The background is changing but just for the text written, not the whole item.

Comment: @FahadUddin how about this solution [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NmFHW/1/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `padding:10px` on your `a` tag, not the `.nav`.  This way you'll have the entire link area change color from top to bottom.  (You also have to add `display: block;` to your `a` as well.

```
.nav a{
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-style:italic;
  margin-right:10px;
  padding:10px;
  display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/4wWe5/)

Comment: Thanks. I am implementing your solution here(http://www.startupsandfinance.com/) but there is a weird padding between the menu. Works fine on fiddle.

Comment: You have some extra whitespace in your code after the `<i class="s-arrow-white-down"></i>` element. Take that out and you'll remove the padding you're seeing below the `ul`

Comment: Also, remove the `<i>` tag itself. Because it has a defined height, it'll take up space in the layout. As far as I can tell, you're not using it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think i achieved what you want by using Jquery.
I edited the css in order to remove your attempt of changing the background, that i implemented in Jquery.

```
CSS:

.nav{background:#454545;line-height:1;overflow:hidden;position:relative; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;   padding-left:10px;}

.nav a{
    color:#fff;text-decoration:none;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-right:10px;
}

    .nav i{position:relative;top:-3px}
    .nav li{float:left;overflow:hidden}
    .nav ul{list-style:none;margin:0;overflow:hidden;padding:0;width:100%}
    .nav .item{display:block;font-family:Oswald,Arial Narrow,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15.6px;line-height:1;padding:5px 8px;text-transform:uppercase}​
```

then in the `head` of your html file include the Jquery library. You can download it and host it on your server or use Google's CDN for the library, like this:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now in your HTML `body` add the jquery functions i coded for you:

```
$("li").mouseover(function () {
    $(".nav").css("background-color","#000");
});

$("li").mouseout(function () {
    $(".nav").css("background-color","#454545");
});
```

The background of the nav bar changes when the mouse hover on the `li` (each button). If this is what you want, it's alright, else if you want something different let me know and i'll change it.

Here you can find a DEMO on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNhdg/7/)

Comment: Thanks but you got me wrong(I think I have not given a good enough explanation of the question). I actually meant that the menu item which is being hovered should completely get its color changed. Nice work though

Comment: oh then it was simpler to do. I change it as you want. What could should the menu item have? If you tell me i change it. And the general background of the navigation bar shouldn't change? Only each menu item that is hovered? @FahadUddin

Comment: Do you want this? Check the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/9Epnh/2/ If yes, i edit my answer with the new solution. Please let me know @FahadUddin

Comment: Yes only the item. I created something from the advice of @Scrimothy below. Here(http://jsfiddle.net/4e3dZ/) is the link. It works fine in the fiddle but not on the website(www.startupsandfinance.com)

Comment: Your Fiddle is the same as I posted in my question. If you observe the background changed on hover, its not the whole menu item whose background is being changed but just the text.

Comment: okay, then before editing the code, i take a look at the website because there may be something that interferes with it. @FahadUddin

Comment: I am finally done. It was a stylesheet which was the problem.

Comment: Checking your website i also saw it was a stylesheet problem. Besides there are 8 stylesheets in total and some target the same element so you will have to override the standard css properties unless you want to change the original stylesheet. @FahadUddin

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
.nav{background:#454545;line-height:1;overflow:hidden;position:relative; padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;   padding-left:10px;}

.nav a{
color:#fff;text-decoration:none;
font-style:italic;
margin-right:10px;
} 

.nav i{position:relative;top:-3px}
.nav li{float:left;overflow:hidden}
.nav ul{list-style:none;margin:0;overflow:hidden;padding:0;width:100%}
.nav .item{display:block;font-family:Oswald,Arial Narrow,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15.6px;line-height:1;padding:5px 8px;text-transform:uppercase}
.nav .item:hover{background:#454545;color:#FFF}
.nav .active{background:#454545}
.nav:hover{
        color:#FFF;
        background:#000;            

}
```

​

Comment: That will change the nav colour regardless of where you hover on the nav element.